# get status user in telegram every 1 minute

Tags: python, sockets, telegram, telethon

I want to check a user's online status every 1 minute.
I used the following code but after a while I received the following error.

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events, sync
import time

api_id = my_api_id
api_hash = my_api_hash
username = my_username

client = TelegramClient(username, api_id, api_hash)
client.start()
while True:
    account = client.get_entity(target_username)
    print(account.status.to_dict())
    time.sleep(60)
```

Error after working for a while:

```
A wait of 56063 seconds is required (caused by ResolveUsernameRequest)
```

1. How can i get status user in telegram for every 1 minute?(unlimited)
2. Is there a socket that sends the status of users?

Answer (score 1):

The closest you can get is [`events.UserUpdate`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/quick-references/events-reference.html#userupdate), for things like "user is typing" and so on.

```
@client.on(events.UserUpdate)
async def handler(event):
    ...  # use event
```

You can also use the user ID instead of the username which has lower flood limits. However, Telegram can still suspect of API misuse and issue any flood limits it wants.